# Push Notification in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am creating a mobile application using Phonegap.I want to create a push notification using FCM.I used cordova-plugin-firebase plugin.But it shows error.Really am stuck in the project

Comment: what have you done so far ?? please post your code here.

Comment: i installed the below plugin  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="0.1.18" />

Comment: post your error here, what error you are getting ?

Comment: i placed the above plugin and placed the below code in my device ready   window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
    // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
    console.log(token);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});

Comment: It shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: It seem there is syntax error in your .js file. check if you have type : somewhere in your file.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install the plugin (which you already did)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.18 --save
```

2) From your firebase account download two files and keep the files in your root folder :

```
google-services.json
GoogleService-Info.plist
```

3) Write this code in your onDeviceReady() method :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {  
  window.FirebasePlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token) {
    //save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
     console.log(token);
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
 });
}
```

Here the full index.js code :

```
var app = { 
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    window.FirebasePlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token) {
        //save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
         console.log(token);
      }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
},
};
```

Comment: Is there any need to add the external file link in index.html file?

Comment: i didnt added GoogleService-Info.plist  file,I want just only for Android.So GoogleService-Info.plist  file is mandatory?

Comment: No its for ios only,

Comment: Plugin installed successfully

Comment: I think it is not prob with firebase, i think there is problem with your js file, please recheck.

Comment: I dint get the token value.App getting closed when i added the above code

Comment: is there any need to add the external file link in index.html file?file like google-services.json

Comment: No, only the steps i mention above. I wont be able to help if you dont post your code or your error stacktrace.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined   This is the arror

Comment: window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
    // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
    console.log(token);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
        $(document).on("deviceready", function () {
       
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        if(window.devextremeaddon) {
            window.devextremeaddon.setup();
        }
        $(document).on("backbutton", function () {
            DevExpress.processHardwareBackButton();
        });
       
        });